# Unstable LAN network

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet, lan

I have Dell vostro 3558 laptop with ubuntu 18.10. I do not face any issues when I am using Wifi. However when I am using Ethernet LAN for internet, it keeps disconnecting after 10-15 minutes and again reconnects automatically after 2-3 minutes. I did not face this problem earlier when I would use windows 10.
What could be the issue and how can it be fixed?
How do I check if the hardware is alright?

```
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 3160
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 83
       serial: 18:3d:a2:f8:70:28
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.18.0-17-generic firmware=17.948900127.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:52 memory:f7100000-f7101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 0c
       serial: 84:7b:eb:01:9f:c5
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.046.00-NAPI duplex=full ip=10.10.0.195 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

And

```
/var/log/syslog:Apr 11 08:21:15 ****-Vostro-3558 kernel: [    1.672716] r8168 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from eth0 /var/log/syslog.1:Apr 10 21:04:41 ****-Vostro-3558 kernel: [    1.653284] r8168 0000:07:00.0 enp7s0: renamed from eth0
```

```
oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics, 0.1: added
r8168, 8.046.00, 4.18.0-17-generic, x86_64: installed
```

grep -i enp7s0 /var/log/syslog* output: 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wDbQ888K36/

I have LAN port in my dorm which is provided by the university.

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

timeout 300;
```

Comment: Have you looked at any logs, such as `dmesg`?  If you see any output related to your NIC, please add it to your question.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly should I type in the terminal?

Comment: `dmesg` or `sudo dmesg`.  If you run into problems, try giving a quick search on the topic and you'll likely discover a lot of information.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`. And `grep -i eth0 /var/log/syslog*` and put that output on paste.ubuntu.com. Describe your ethernet cabling path to the router. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I have updated my question with said output.

Comment: Thanks for the info update. Now show me `dkms status` and `grep -i enp7s0 /var/log/syslog*` (note the *) and use paste.ubuntu.com if it's lengthy. Please describe your ethernet cabling from the computer to the router/modem.

Comment: I have updated the question @heynnema .

Comment: I've reviewed your syslog, and I can see the problem that you describe. In this order, try... 1) disable IPv6 in your `Wired Connection` profile, 2) try a **different** cat 5e or cat 6 ethernet cable, 3) try a different LAN port. Show me `grep -v "#" /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Report back.

Comment: As an unrelated side note, I can see that at one point you tried to add a `oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics` dkms driver. It never completed. Is that important?

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the questions. The solutions unfortunatly did not work. Also how does one learn all theses things ?

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question. The solutions sadly did not work. Also how does one learn all theses things ?

Comment: You tried a **different** LAN port, yes? What about the touchpad dkms driver? You learn these things through time and experience... like on-the-job-training :-) Now we'll try removing the ethernet dkms driver, and fall back to the original driver... `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.046.00 -k 4.18.0-17-generic`, then reboot. Retest and report back.

Comment: After removing and rebooting the ethernet connection is not being detected. Also, I checked the LAN port with a friend's laptop, it seems fine.

Comment: How can add the driver again?  I hope updating to 19.04 might fix the problem ? @heynnema

Comment: @mathemather sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Just to confirm, you removed the r8168-dkms driver, and now you don't see the ethernet interface at all? Show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`, and once more show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @mathemather please remember to start comments to me with "@heynnema" or I'll probably miss them... like I did with your Apr 11 comment.

Comment: @heynnema reinstalling driver fixed the problem. (It could also be updating to 19.04). Thanks for your help.