# How to add LAN driver?

Tags: internet, ethernet, lan, 19.04

I used 
`sudo dkms remove r8168/8.046.00 -k 4.18.0-17-generic`
In order to fix unstable LAN connection. Since then my laptop is not detecting LAN. In the meanwhile, I have upgraded to 19.04 and hope that the issue is resolved. How do I get back LAN. I tried `sudo dkms add r8168/8.046.00 -k 4.18.0-17-generic` , but it did not work.
For `sudo dkms add r8168/8.046.00 -k 5.0.0-13-generic` I get Error! DKMS tree already contains: r8168-8.046.00.
When I try `sudo dkms remove r8168/8.046.00 -k 5.0.0-13-generic` I get Error! There is no instance of r8168 8.046.00.

Comment: Please see my latest comment in your prior question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132775/unstable-lan-network

Comment: Although I don't think it's a good idea, you can add back the r8168-dkms driver with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall r8168-dkms`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Ubuntu version uses a different kernel chain. After upgrading to Ubuntu version 19.04 your kernel version changed. To find the new version number type `uname -r`. Then use that in your command. For example:

```
$ uname -r
4.14.110-0414110-generic

$ sudo dkms add r8168/8.046.00 -k 4.14.110-0414110-generic
```

---

To reinstall `dkms` driver for the `rtl8168` use:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall r8168-dkms
```

---

You may not need `dkms` RTL8168 driver add on with version 5.0 kernel. The RTL8169 driver has been improved in this kernel version as per [Linux Kernel 5.0 Released! Check Out The New Features](https://itsfoss.com/linux-kernel-5/):

Here are some of the major new changes in Kernel 5.0:

- AMD Radeon FreeSync support
- Support for a new VegaM
- NVIDIA Xavier display support
- Continued work on Intel Icelake Gen11 graphics
- Initial support for the NXP i.MX8 SoCs
- Support for the Allwinner T3, Qualcomm QCS404, and NXP Layerscape LX2160A
- Intel VT-d Scalable Mode support for Scalable I/O Virtualization
- New Intel Stratix 10 FPGA drivers
- Fixes for F2FS, EXT4 and XFS
- Btrfs file-system restores support for swap files
- Fscrypt Adiantum support for helping with fast data encryption on low-end hardware. This replaces the infamous Speck algorithm by NSA.
- **Realtek R8169 driver improvements**
- Logitech High Resolution Scrolling support
- Raspberry Pi Touchscreen driver
- x86 laptop drivers improvement
- Thunderbolt security enhancement
- Support for the Chameleon96 Intel FPGA board
- Improved power management

The RTL8168 driver has been manually installed by many users because of RTL8169 flaws for their network cards.